# Enter Facebook Canvas Page App after Like of Facebook Page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, iframe, facebook-like, facebook-canvas

I developed a campaign on Facebook for a client, where someone first need to like the page
to reveal exclusive content (typical reveal tab), the exclusive content leads fans to a canvas page app, which is a small flash game where fans can play a slot machine to win free tickets to a event.

After someone is finished playing, they are asked to fill in friends email addresses to invite their friends to also play the game. They will receive an email which directs them directly to the canvas application.

This way we are missing their likes to the initial page itself, is it possible to have a check implemented on the canvas app page whether they like a given page or not.( in this case the fan page with the reveal tab).

Answer (score 2):

You could query the [like table using fql](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/like/).
Other solution is that a link in email which direct user to canvas direct them to application tab on fan page instead.